# Two for-each loops in a recursive function to traverse a file system

Tags: recursion, pseudocode

I'm not looking to get someone to do my assignment for me. I'm just not too sure about what its asking when it comes to the recursive part of the assignment.

This is a recursive function to open the directory and open the files of the computer:

```
For each ChildContainer item in dir 
Create an OrderedList of names 
For each ChildData item of the ChildContainer 
Add the ChildData name to the OrderedList of names
```

Why are there two `for each` statements in the recursive part of the instructions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've made a small tweak to your post to format the pseudocode as code - you can do this by indenting each line by 4 spaces. When asking a question it's a good idea to check the preview before submitting to check the question is easily readable - that way you're more likely to get answers. I've also changed the tags because this doesn't seem to be specific to Java, but is really just a question about recursion.

Answer (score 0):

okies,

Firstly this should not be StackOverflow as it's not a programming question it's a programming theory question that should be asked on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

I think you're missing the point of recursive functions/methods here. The whole point of a recursive function is that it does the nesting for you so you should not need to nest a foreach inside another foreach the function will do that for you.

This is an outline of how to do it, however, i will not provide code as you have said this is an assignment. I don't support plagiarism.

```
PlaceToStore = array of array of dir path (string);

function scanPath(pathToOpen, PlaceToStore){ 
    where dirHandle equals directory reader
    where childrenArray = dirHandle->getChilden
    foreach child in childrenArray do
        if(child is directory) then
            scanPath(child->path, PlaceToStore[child->path]
        else
             placeToStore[child->path] = child->path
       end if
   endforeach
}
```

you should not need a double for each your childData is another directory or file

now this example is a quick outline of a messy way to do it but it shows how recursion should be done in an example that easy to understand.